# Change to async/await syntax

Tags: javascript

I have some code that print in console a number series start for 1, 
continuing for 2 and so on. I've done it with promises but now I want to change my promise script to async/await mode, but It doesn't work.

What I tried was this:

```
const alwaysThrows = () => {
    throw new Error("OH NOES");
};

const iterate = (integer) => {
    console.log(integer);
    return integer + 1;

};

const prom = Promise.resolve(iterate(1));



const manageOk = async () => {
    let result = await prom;
    console.log(result);



}

manageOk()
```

but I dont know how get the rest of numbers.

This is my original code:

```
const alwaysThrows = () => {
    throw new Error("OH NOES");
};

const iterate = (integer) => {
    console.log(integer);
    return integer + 1;

};

const prom = Promise.resolve(iterate(1));


prom
.then((value) => iterate(value))
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.then(alwaysThrows)
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   const manageOk = async (val) => {
        return await iterate(val);
    }

    manageOk(1)
    .then(res => manageOk(res))
    .then(manageOk)
    .then(manageOk)
    .then(manageOk)
```